# What is the funciton of $dx'^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-operators

Let's say same point in two co-ordinate system has the following relation from partial derivatives,

$$dx'=\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial x'}{\partial y} dy$$
and
$$dy'=\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial y'}{\partial y} dy.$$

I have to derive the conditions for $$ dx'^2 + dy'^2 \propto dx^2 + dy^2. $$

Now my question is how do define $dx'^2$?
My memory and hunch says, it should be
$$ dx'^2 = \left( \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \right)^2 dx^2 + 2 \frac{\partial x'^2}{\partial x \partial y} dxdy + \left( \frac{\partial x'}{\partial y} \right)^2 dy^2$$

However, I'm not sure. Is it correct?

Also, could anyone tell me a good text to revise these stuffs from. I did them a long time ago and forgot.

Comment: The expression you wrote is not $dx'^2$ but $d^2x'$, the second differential of $x'$ as a  function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What does $\alpha$ mean?

Comment: It is not $\alpha$, it is $\propto$ = proportional to.

Comment: @GReyes, In that case what is the expression for $dx'^2$?

Comment: Actually, what you have is neither of them (just did not notice that you have the squares, not the pure second derivatives in your expression). $dx'^2$ would simply be what you have, replacing the mixed second derivative by $ (dx'/dx)(dx'/dy)$ (you just square your expression for $dx'$).

Comment: The second differential would be $d^2x'=(\partial^2x'/\partial x^2)\,dx^2+2(\partial^2x'/\partial x\partial y)\,dxdy+(\partial^2x'/\partial y^2)\,dy^2$

Comment: @GReyes, thanks. This solved the problem. :)